# Generating permutation matrices of a 2 dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, permutation

I am wanting to generate all the square permutation matrices for an input d (which is a prime number). I know there are examples on how to do this for all permutations in general, but I am looking for permutation matrices which satisfy the mathematical definition;

A permutation matrix is a matrix obtained by permuting the rows of an dxd **identity** matrix according to some permutation of the numbers 1 to d. Every **row and column** therefore contains precisely a single 1 with 0s everywhere else.

e.g for 2x2, [[1,0],[0,1]] and [[0,1],[1,0]] satisfy this, while [[1,1],[0,0]], etc... do not, so I am hoping this isn't a duplicate question. I have a code which does this and my test is that I should have d! matrices. When I get to 11, I should get 11! matrices but I get the error that my code is shutting down due to memory loss. I am hoping someone has a more efficient way of solving this problem as I would like to go to larger prime numbers;

```
import math
import numpy as np
import cmath
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
from itertools import permutations, chain
from pprint import pprint
from numpy import ndarray
from numpy import linalg as LA


d=5
print("Prime dimension",d)
a=[1]+[0 for _ in range(d-1)]
N=[] 
P=[]
Pdagger=[]
for p in multiset_permutations(a):
    N.append(p)

#Generate a list of ALL the permutation matrices including Identity (last)
for n in multiset_permutations(N):
    n
    P.append(n)
print(len(P))
```

I am running my code in an IPython Jupyter notebook if that helps. I understand this may not be the best/most efficient way to run this but I'm looking for any advice anyone can give me. All the libraries imported at the top are relevant to the code later on.

Comment: 11! 11x11 matrices would contain nearly 5 billion entries all together, most of which are 0 in the case of permutation matrices. Why not write a generator for them instead?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain this further? Maybe the problem I'm trying to answer may need some more context!

Comment: 11! 11x11 matrices is too much for most machines to hold in their memory at once. Presumably you aren't trying to do this for no reason at all but instead are going to iterate over them. A generator in Python is a lazy list which produces the elements on the fly. You should be able to write a generator so that e.g. you can have a loop which starts like `for M in permutation.matrices(11):`

Comment: If `A` is the 11x11 identity matrix represented as a list of rows then `itertools.permutations(A)` is *already* an iterator over all permutation matrices. Why the desire to assemble them all into a multi-gigabyte list?

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. There is no reason I have to keep the permutation matrices in memory at this point. Is `permutation.matrices` a list of them? 
Also, by `A`, do you mean `a` in my code? For say d=3, `a=[1,0,0]`, then `N=[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]`, and `P` is a list of matrices where the rows of N have been permuted. So I'm not sure I understand your comment. I also apologise for what may be obvious questions.

Comment: `permutation.matrices` isn't anything until you define it. It shouldn't be a list if you want `n` to be 11. `itertools.permutations(A)` is probably adequate -- but if you want to mutate the matrices which are produced then you would need to create copies of them to avoid aliasing bugs. 11! is nearly 40 million and simply producing each permutation isn't cheap, so if you plan to do anything at all complicated with each one then your code might take a while to run.

Comment: Okay, so I have tried;
`A=np.identity(d)
B=itertools.permutations(A)`
This gives me a list, `B` of all my permutation matrices. Is this what you're getting at? For some context, I intend on iterating each permutation matrix conjugated (PXP(dagger)) with the Pauli X/Sigma X matrix (if you're familiar) and writing the period of each one to a file. The period being how many conjugations I perform until I get my original matrix back.
I feel like using a generator sounds like my best bet, but I'm not too sure how tog o about doing this.

Comment: `itertools.permutations(A)` isn't a list in Python 3. It is a generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too large for a comment. Here is the sort of thing that I had in mind:

```
import itertools

def I(n):
    A = []
    for i in range(n):
        A.append([1 if j == i else 0 for j in range(n)])
    return A

#tests:

A = I(3)

for m in itertools.permutations(A):
    print('\n'.join(str(row) for row in m))
    print('')

A = I(11)
count = 0
for m in itertools.permutations(A):
    count = count + m[0][0] #for testing purposes
print(count)
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]

[1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]

[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]

[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]

[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]

3628800
```

This take about 10 seconds to run and the final number is 11!/11 (which makes sense).

Comment: Thank you. How come we have 11!/11? This number is familiar as in my problem d!/d is the number of equivalence classes we have (one way I plan to reduce the size of the problem). However, I'm not sure why that has appeared here - why are we only counting the matrices that have the top left element entry of 1?
For my iteration process, I imagine here, I build another loop inside this loop, where I carry m forward as the permutation matrix.

Comment: I was just counting the matrices which have a 1 in the upper left hand corner -- 1 out of 11 have this property. It was a random test -- I just wanted to do *something* with each matrix produced.